# Oracle Integration Cloud - Libraries - JavaScript functions

Tags: oracle-integration-cloud

I'm having a problem with JS within OIC. I need to create a simple function that will return all values if condition is met. Like so -

function get_email_data_prc(p_email_template) {

if (p_email_template === 'METADATA_NOT_FOUND') {

```
x_email_subject = '- MW Job has Failed';

p_status = 'test error';
```

} else if (p_email_template === 'NO_FILE_FOUND') {

```
x_email_subject = '- MW Job has Failed';

p_status = 'test success';
```

}

return x_email_subject;

}

and I need this function to return more then just x_email_subject but also p_status, but Oracle does not seem to allow that inside of the function. Have you had an issue like that?

I managed to do workaround, and add

const output = [x_email_subject ,p_status ]

return output;

but then I'll just receive two values separated by comma and it can't be mapped to perticular field in the mapping further in integration.

Seeking your help guys!

I think I've tried everything and the closest was that I received two values but comma separated, and not two separate values